# I have an app with portrait support only , but i want to play video in MPMoviewController in both Portrait as well as Landscape, How to do it

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an  tab bar and navigation based app with portrait support only , but i want to play video in MPMoviePlayerController in both Portrait as well as Landscape, How can I do this

Answer (score 1):

Try supporting all the orientations in your project properties and returning `NO` from the below method in all `ViewControllers` except the one you wanted to show `Landscape`.

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    // return YES for the desired View controller. :)
}`

Comment: I think you also need to add  (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations { return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; } if you are using iOS6+

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using `UINavigationController` the app will use its rotation logic